# Ionic Close App or Refresh upon open

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there a way that when a person goes away from the app, it shuts itself down. With this, when they reopen the app, it goes back to splash screen like they are opening the app fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be done like this,
you can add event on pause. when screen goes sleep the pause event fire

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
```

and in function **onPause** you can close the app or whatever you want.

Similarly you can do onResume functionality like

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```

and onResume you can check its state or can redirect to splash or whatever your scenario is.

Happy Coding!